# get Json data from request with Django

Tags: python, json, django

I'm trying to develop a very simple script in Django, I'd collect a Json data from the request and then store all data in the database.

I developed one python script that I'm using to send the Json data to the Django view, but I'm doing something wrong and I can't understand what, because every time that I run it,I've got "Malformed data!".

Can someone helps me? what am I doing wrong?

Sender.py

```
import json
import urllib2

data = {
         'ids': ["milan", "rome","florence"]
}

req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1:8000/value/')
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')

response = urllib2.urlopen(req, json.dumps(data))
```

Django view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
from models import *

from django.http import StreamingHttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def value(request):

  try:
      data = json.loads(request.body)
      label = data['label']
      url = data ['url']
      print label, url
  except:
      return HttpResponse("Malformed data!")
  return HttpResponse("Got json data")
```

Comment: You have to correct your dictionary as it does not contains any key 'label' or 'url' in Sender.py file.

Comment: @Prateek I changed the key 'ids' in the python script with 'label' and I removed the line url = data[ 'url' ] and also the url variable in the print, but I have the same problem, when I refresh the browser page, it shows me only "Malformed data !"

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary "data" in sender.py contains only one value with key "ids" but in view.py you are trying to access keys "label" and "url" in this parsed dictionary.

Comment: I changed the key 'ids' in the python script with 'label' and I removed the line url = data[ 'url' ] and also the url variable in the print, but I have the same problem, when I refresh the browser page, it shows me only "Malformed data !", the error is in the line data = json.loads(request.body), am I doing something wrong in the Sender script?

Comment: @macco Try to check what exception message is, use debugging tools for understanding what request body contain.